# Store.filter() does not work for special character

Tags: extjs

I had a requirement to filter the textfield based on input characters, its working fine when we give normal characters, but when we enter special characters its not filtering.
How can I filter a textfield based on special characters like "Q/D?F" or "23/12/2017" in ExtJS

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some fiddle resembling same issue ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the forum and read up on the help centre to find out how to ask a question. We are here to help troubleshoot your code. Please update your question with what you have done and someone can have a look at it.